What is the parameter name for the pdf file name I pass to ghost script?
I can print a file using Ghostscript via the command prompt using the below command:
"C:\Program Files\gs\gs10.03.0\bin\gswin64c.exe" -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -sOutputFile="%printer%LaserPrinter01" "C:\Testing\JobSheet.pdf"
However, I need to call this from a 3rd party application where you have to specify the parameters:

What is the parameter name for the "C:\Testing\JobSheet.pdf" value?
I have tried the parameter '-input' and '-filename' but these does not work.

There is no parameter name. Input files are simply passed on the command line, you can pass more than one at a time.

codelessplatforms dialog guide says use "quoted spaces" actually suggests all parameters be ideally "double quoted". Hmmm, I am unsure that should always be the case!
It is not clear how it adds separators between switches, but these are the ONLY separated parts you need. This is based on the premise that the document names will be added after the -f parameter.

    "-sDEVICE#mswinpr2"     BSTR     NULL
    -o                      BSTR     "%printer%LaserPrinter01"
    -f                      BSTR     NULL

NOTE the quotes around the EXE name
The DEVICE name needs to be a single string, so is followed by NULL. The -o is all that is needed to set "output", which goes to the "named printer". Thus needs to be quoted to avoid future space issues. The -f (filenames) parameter is added since you seem to think one is needed, but -f is optional.
When you are testing, you should see a confirming progress dialog, as a % processed. If you wish, AFTER testing, to disable that cancel button, then add the -dNoCancel parameter in place of the first NULL
